# Can the existence of space be in the absence of matter/energy and time?

Tags: time, existence, universe, space, matter

This question has potentially a long answer or ironically a very short answer if the question is a load of nonsense, however, I'm going to ask it anyhow.

I propose there are three fundamental
components of existence, space, matter/energy and time

Can they exist independently,  or is each dependent upon the others existence for it to exist.

If they can exist independently, then I would propose there can be a 'sequence' to their existence.

If they can exist independently and existence is not dependent upon time, then space could exist without matter/energy or time, and there are other permutations of existence such as, the existence of matter/energy without space or time or the existence of time without space or matter/energy.

If they are all dependent upon each other, then they have to have existed simultaneously and thus temporarily, and each existed at the same time as time existed.

Is my deduction logically sound and exhaustive, and is there any physical evidence that significantly supports a particular part of this deduction over the other parts of it?

Comment: In modern physics, space and time only exist jointly as spacetime, and "simultaneously" depends on the reference frame and cannot be used as in your statements. Positing spacetime as independent of matter/energy is called spacetime substantivalism and it is controversial, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-holearg/).

Comment: does not time imply distance? If there is no matter nor is there distance. Is not space required for matter? matter and distance require space. Do not all of them require awareness??

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I personally don't associate time with distance other than it is necessary to be able to move and movement requires space. Space can either be finite and bounded or finite and unbounded or infinite and bounded or infinite and unbounded. Can you explain a little more what you mean by 'does not time imply distance?'. I would argue that they would not not all require awareness as life has not existed to have awareness since time existed, unless you invoke God as awareness?

Comment: in theory: yes, practically: no one experienced yet? can a "point" "exist" (in absence of matter/energy time)? i guess so, because there seems to be no "causal relation" between these terms... and they are different in their meaning/effect... still no one ever "saw" a point"/"a/the vacuum"/..a circle.../"energy"

Comment: i better differentiate the "world"/"time"/"reality" into "being" and "non-being" , the first one i call "persistence"/"durability"/"presence" the latter I (+ lao-tsu translators) call *existence* /"eternity"/"non-presence" (/past+future) ...for "space", i "elaborate": "limited space" persists/is there, "unlimited/empty space" exists/is *not* there!!

Comment: "matter" is *there*! "energy" is not there (it exists). ("movement"(="way") of matter neither!?) "time"!? we can separate into "now" (=is there) and "before/after" (is not there)